# Testing if 2 Sprites are touching in Javascript

Tags: javascript, sprite, collision

I am currently working on a simple game.
I have a projectile and an enemy. I want the variable **colliding** to be 1 whenever the given Sprites touch. Here is my code:

```
if (projectileposX >= enemyposX + 100 || projectileposX + 160 <= enemyposX) { colliding = 0; }
if (projectileposY >= enemyposY + 100 || projectileposY + 160 <= enemyposY) { colliding = 0; }
else { colliding = 1; }
```

The "projectile" sprite is 160x160px big. 
The "enemy" sprite is 100x100px big.

I wanted to now test for the variable **colliding** and run code if the value equals 1.
Problem is: it acts like colliding is always 1, although I *believe* that should not be the case.

But because I know its always the problem of the user and I cant see any mistakes I am asking here if anybody can see something wrong.

I also tried combining both if statements into one, resulting in the same weird acting:

```
if (projectileposY >= enemyposY + 100 || projectileposY + 160 <= enemyposY || projectileposX >= enemyposX + 100 || projectileposX + 160 <= enemyposX) {
colliding = 0;
} else {
colliding = 1;
}
if (colliding == 1) {
//do stuff
}
```

just to clarify: The if-statement doesnt test if it touches, it test if it's **not** touching.

Comment: You need else if... your code totally ignores the first if since it will just get overwritten by the y check.

Comment: I think that would not work (it doesnt) because it tests if the sprites are not touching. I could split the if statements into 4 or combine them into 1 and it wouldnt make a difference.

Comment: It ignores the X check..... You really should combine the x and y check into one line

Comment: Your code ignores the X check and only relies on the Y check....

Comment: My Code is now:
if (projectileposY >= enemyposY + 100 || projectileposY + 160 <= enemyposY || projectileposX >= enemyposX + 100 || projectileposX + 160 <= enemyposX) { colliding = 0; }
else { colliding = 1; } 
if (colliding == 1) {
//do stuff
}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I knew I was the problem (again). When declaring the position of the enemy to test it using this code, I declared them wrong. Those variables then stayed undefined and as a result it didnt know what to do with it.
Both codes up there are working perfectly fine now without changing a single letter of code.
Still thanks to everyone who at least tried to help.

Comment: `I knew I was the problem (again)` XD. Welcome to programming :)